# Table Width with webpart

Tags: web-part, design

I'm trying to figure out why the webpart content(in this case its a Newsfeed) is showing(exceeding the width) outside of the TD Width of 40% (see image in the screenshot). Should I be using px for the webpart instead of %?

[image]I have a parent table that is set to 100% and wanted to have the web parts follow the width of the tds...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

(I think) Because that Newsfeed uses its own layout

[image]

So you have to add CSS with higher specificity to overrule it to the layout you want

Comment: What;s weird is that in IE when I decreased the width to 550px, it shows perfectly in IE and Mozilla but then in Google Chrome it still exceeds.

Comment: this is the id .ms-comm-forumContainer. When I inspected element in Chrome, the max-width is690px but when I inspected element in IE, it shows max-width :550px which is what is correct.